# Associated graded ring of a quotient

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a ring A and an ideal $I \subseteq A$ we can form its associated graded ring with respect to $I$
$$
Gr_I(A)= A/I \oplus I/I^2 \oplus I^2/I^3 \oplus \ldots
$$
I wondered if there is a way to relate this ring to an associated graded ring of a quotient of $A$, for example $Gr_J(A/\mathfrak{a})$ for $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq I$ and $J = I/\mathfrak{a}$.

The motivation for my question originates from a rather special case I have encountered. There $A$ has characteristic $p > 0$ and $I = (x_1, \ldots, x_r)$. It would be nice to have an isomorphism
$$
Gr_I(A)/(\bar{x_1}^p, \ldots \bar{x_r}^p) \cong Gr_J(A/\mathfrak{a})
$$
where $\mathfrak{a} = (x_1^p, \ldots, x_r^p)$, $J$ as above and a bar denotes reduction modulo $I^2$, but I could neither prove nor disprove this relation and so I started to think about the general problem.

Any thoughts on the matter are appreciated.